# Javascript Inheritance and the words "this" and "that"

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, this

I have a class where I use its methods as event listeners, so I don't use `this` but `that` in the methods.

This is the base class:

```
function Modal(){
     var that = this;
     this.opened = false;
     this.open = function(){ 
         that.opened = true;
         var id = this.id;
         // more code
     };
     this.close = function () { 
         if (that.opened) // do something;
     };
}
```

This is the inherited class:

```
function ModalBook(){
     var that = this;
     this.open = function(){ 
         that.opened = true;
         var id = this.id;
         // more code
     };
}
ModalBook.prototype = new Modal();

var modalBook = new ModalBook();
```

Now the value of `modal.opened` is true when the modal is opened but when it's closed the value is false.

On debugging on the line of `this.close`, I saw that `that` is an instance of `Modal`, and `modalBook` is an instance of `ModalBook`.

So my question is: How to preserve the value of `this` in both methods for `modalBook`?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 2):

What's happening there is that with `ModalBook.prototype=new Modal()` `ModalBook` is 'inheriting' `Modal`. Variables belong to each constructor in their scopes and properties are overwritten. So:

- `that` in `Modal` will stay locally in `Modal`
- `that` in `ModalBook` will be an instante of `ModalBook`
- But the only `open()` method that will exist is `ModalBook.open()` (you're overwritting the other one) where `that` is an instance of `ModalBook` and the other `that` doesn't exist in that scope.

I think you have a design problem. Maybe use properties with different name for the `that`s.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The line `ModalBook.prototype = new Modal();` means *all* new ModalBook points to one, single, new Modal object, and this Model object is the `that` in the close method.

This object is *not* re-created for each new `ModalBook`.  This is prototype inheritance.

---

**Fix**

If you do it correctly, there is no need to capture the `this`.

Here is a better way to code it, traditionally.

```
var Modal = function(){ return this; };
Modal.prototype = {
   opened : false,
   open : function(){ 
      this.opened = true;
      var id = this.id;
      // more code
  },
  close : function () { 
      if (this.opened) // do something;
  },
};

// Old IE may not have Object.assign or Object.create. shims available.
var ModalBook = function(){ Modal.call( this ); return this; };
ModalBook.prototype = Object.assign( Object.create( Modal.prototype ), { 
   open : function(){
      this.opened = true;
      var id = this.id;
      console.log( 'open2' );
   } 
} );

var modalBook = new ModalBook();
```

---

**Without constructor**

Or if you prefer not using constructor at all, like me.

```
/* In ES6.  Runs on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari.  Use Babel to run on IE. */

const Modal = {
   opened: false,
   create     () { return Object.create( Modal ).initialise(); },
   initialise () { return this; },
   open       () { /* ... */ },
   close      () { /* ... */ },
};

const ModalBook = {
   __proto__ : Modal,
   create     () { return Object.create( ModalBook ).initialise(); },
   open       () { /* ... */ },
};

var modalBook = ModalBook();
```